# Defining own style for Hyperlink in JavaFX

Tags: css, hyperlink, javafx

I am new to JavaFX programming, and I need to develop an own style for Hyperlink objects. Basically is:

- black color when is created, disabled, pressed and any other case before the following second case.
- blue color after an email, that is written in this hyperlink, was succesfully sent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I defined the class and the style for its pseudo-classes in main.css, and I attached my style to the Hyperlink with this code link.getStyleClass().add("custom_hyperlink"). However , it does not do anything.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the css you used for your `custom_hyperlink` style class?